# Update multiple inputs programmatically in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I have a form where I need to update multiple other form fields when another field is updated. For example, I have a contact name and depending on the contact name, I need to update the values of the email and phone.

```
<template>
  <custom-input :value="contact.name" @input="event => contact.name = event.target.value" />
  <custom-input :value="contact.phone" @input="event => contact.phone = event.target.value" />
  <custom-input :value="contact.email" @input="event => contact.email = event.target.value" /> 
</template>

<script>
...
props: {
  contact: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  }
},
watch: 
  "contact.name": function(value) {
    if (this.contact.name === "john") {
      this.contact.email = "john@email.com"
      this.contact.phone = "1111111111"
    } else if (this.contact.name === "ed") {
      this.contact.email = "ed@email.com"
      this.contact.phone = "2222222222"  
    }
  }
}

...
</script>
```

I understand that Vue doesn't like this because it separates the DOM from the data model. My first thought was to use `$refs` but those are read only. What's the right way to do this?

Another thought I had was to set the value of `name` and `phone` to computed properties. The problem with that is that it doesn't get watched on the form in the parent component.

This might also tie in with my misunderstanding of "two-way" binding. I've always reasoned that the form is one way, and the data within the component's script is the other which it is not. So, what's the other way?

A final thought I have is that I might have to emit an event instead?

```
<template>
  <custom-input :value="contact.name" @input="event => contact.name = event.target.value" />
  <custom-input ref="phone" :value="contact.phone" @input="event => contact.phone = event.target.value" />
  <custom-input ref="email" :value="contact.email" @input="event => contact.email = event.target.value" /> 
</template>

<script>
...
props: {
  contact: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  }
},
watch: 
  "contact.name": function(value) {
    if (this.contact.name === "john") {
       this.$refs.email.$emit("input", "john@email.com")
       this.$refs.phone.$emit("input", "111111111111")
    } else if (this.contact.name === "ed") {
       this.$refs.email.$emit("input", "ed@email.com")
       this.$refs.phone.$emit("input", "222222222222")
    }
  }
}
```

That doesn't seem to work either. Bummer.

**Edit**

Fixed syntax errors

**Edit 2**

Showed that `input` was actually a separate child component

Comment: Aside from the unnecessary separation of `:value` and `@input` (just use `v-model`), I don't see any issue with what you're doing here. Maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @DecadeMoon It doesn't work sadly. Should it?

Comment: Nevermind, I re-read your code and found some syntax errors. See my answer.

Comment: Those edits you made clears things up, thanks. I still think `v-model` can (and should) be used here, but since we're dealing with a custom component, you may not be receiving the native event object for the `input` event that it emits. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @DecadeMoon How would I know when that event is received? I know it's firing based on the Vue console but it throws an error for `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"`

Comment: Right, because `event` is not a native [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event), so `event.target` is likely `undefined`. What is `event`? That depends on the implementation of `<custom-input>`. I'm guessing it would likely just be the string value directly, so try `@input="value => contact.name = value"`.

Comment: @DecadeMoon So the issue is only with the event emissions because it works fine if I use the input directly. I'm just not clear on how to $emit that event back to the child component. Is `this.$refs.email.$emit("input", "john@email.com")` the right signature?

Comment: You typically don't emit events down to child components. If you want to update the value of the element, change the value that is bound to its `value` prop. What are you trying to achieve by emitting an event to the child?

Comment: @DecadeMoon I think the difficulty I'm having is that the interface to child elements is not clear. In React I pass a function and I call that function. In Vue, the interface is a DOM synthetic event which is fine when I'm using the UI but problematic when I try to invoke it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that you are trying to modify the value of `props` which prohibited by Vue. All child components cannot modify the data in `props` flown from the parent, because it makes the data flow harder to understand. you can read more about this at the official site: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

This is why Vue also have `data` which is local private memory that can be modified by the component.

So to solve you problem you need to copy data in `props` to `data` on the child component when it is mounted and modify the value of `data` instead.

This is the updated code example (Codepen is also updated) that does exactly what you want.

Template:

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <my-form :contact="contact"></my-form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
Vue.component('my-form', {
  data() {
    return { name: '', phone: '', email: '' }
  },
  props: {
    contact: { type: Object, required: true }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.name = this.contact.name;
    this.phone = this.contact.phone;
    this.email = this.contact.email;
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <input v-model="name" />
      <input v-model="phone"/>
      <input v-model="email"/>
      <p>
        value of input: {{ JSON.stringify({ name, phone, email }) }}
      </p>
    </div>
  `,
    watch: {
      name(value) {
        if(value === 'john') {
           this.phone = '123456';
           this.email = 'test@gmail.com';
        }
      }
    }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { contact: { name: 'initial name', phone: '123456', email: 'initial.email@gmail.com' } }
  }
})
```

And my updated code pen: https://codepen.io/aptarmy/pen/PoqgpNJ

Comment: Great! Let me try to implement this.

Comment: @user3162553 I have tested it, and it works. please tell me if it works for you.

Comment: It does work but I cannot change the phone or email values when state is pre-selected. That's just supposed to be the default. I forgot to mention that though, so I will upvote this regardless.

Comment: @user3162553 I just updated my code example in my answer to make `phone` and `email` updatable. My Codepen is also updated, so please check it out.

Comment: So this actually doesn't entirely work as it won't persist the manual update when it's unfocused. @Pakpoom Tiwakornkit

Comment: Cloud you elaborate on that @user3162553?

Comment: Steps to reproduce on codepen. 1. Add name of "john" 2. adjust phone number 3. focus on name again. Observe that phone number reverts back to 12345.

Comment: @user3162553 my code is updated. The cause of problems why your code doesn't work is explained in my updated answer. This is because you are trying to modify the value of `props` which is not allowed by Vue. Data flown through `props` is One-Way binding. please reread my answer, take a look at updated Codepen, update your code, and please tell me if it works now.